# Optional thousand-separator processes incomplete string

Tags: regex

I need to process numbers that may have optional thousand-separators, such as 1234567 and 1,234,567
I naively assumed I could achieve this with
`(\d{1,3}([,]?(\d{3}))*)`
This, however, matches only 123456 (not the 7) and 1,234,567 (correctly)
However, if I specify an explicit number of matches (2 in this case)
`(\d{1,3}([,]?(\d{3})){2})`
or a bound (such as \b)
`(\d{1,3}([,]?(\d{3}))*)\b`
the full match is performed.
Why does the “greedy” * quantifier stop after the first match in the first regex?

Comment: It matches the whole string here: https://regex101.com/r/9BcTzH/1

Comment: But not the case without commas 
https://regex101.com/r/8bOjbc/1.

Comment: It's because the first `\d{1,3}` is greedy, so it matches `123`. Then the rest has to match groups of 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match both numbers with, and without, proper comma thousands separators, then I would use an alternation:

```
^(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)$
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, but what I do not understand is the regex behavior (why the third match is not performed). This is one of the few situations when adding a bound increases the number of matches.

Comment: See the @Barmar answer for an explanation as to why your current regex does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `\d{1,3}` is greedy, so it matches `123` at the beginning of the number. Then the rest of the regexp will only match groups of exactly 3 digits because it uses `\d{3}`. A regular expression doesn't try to match the longest possible string, so it won't backtrack and shorten the match for `\d{1,3}` to make the rest of the regexp go further.

But if you add a word boundary `\b` at the end, it no longer matches with that 3-digit prefix. That causes it to backtrack until it's able to match groups of 3 digits ending with a word boundary.